# Simple Exec Insert

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

the issue is I think I've done something wrong, I just don't know what. I've tried try/catch, every other part of this code functions properly (I've echoed everything), but nothing is be inserted into "text". I'm 99% sure it isn't privileges, also as a general question is it ok to use exec when you're just shooting around data in your server and from other urls? Hope to get some replies.

```
<?php
include('simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php');  
$html = new simple_html_dom();  
$html->load_file('http://www.youtube.com/live/all/videos?sort=dd&tag_id=&view=41');
$count = 0;
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=scraper', 'user', 'aa');
$string = $pdo->query('SELECT text FROM urls');
while ($row = $string->fetch())
{
  $links[] = $row['text'];
}
foreach($html->find('[class=content-item-title yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2]') as $element)
{
$array[$count]=$element->href;
foreach ($links as $link)
{
if (strpos($array[$count], $link) == false)
{
$pdo->exec('INSERT INTO urls SET
text=$array[$count]');
}
}
$count += 1;
}
?>
```

Comment: your [insert statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) is wrong, you don't take advantage of [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and parametrize the query, and if you want allow SQL injection by putting the input directly in the query like that, you would need `'. $array[$count] .'\''`  Flagging as non constructive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this

```
$pdo->exec('INSERT INTO urls SET text=$array[$count]');
```

use this

```
$pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO urls SET text=?')->execute(array($array[$count]));
```

Take a time and read about [prepare in PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php). Also about [Variable parsing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).